# json::write in Vivado

Tags: tcl, vivado

I am encountering an error while trying to write a dict into a json file.

After a search on the web I have been found this as solution:

```
::json::write object {*}$myDict
```

However, when I run it I have got:

```
invalid command name "::json::write"
```

it should be a standard package od Tcl, but it seems is not.

I am using the Vivado 18.3 interpreter.

Thank you for any help, 
    Vito

Comment: The `json` package in question is part of Tcllib, and not Tcl itself. Have you got Tcllib installed on that machine?

Comment: Thank you, Donald! 

I am using the Tcl interpreter provided by Vivado and I was able to run successfully ::jason::json2dict. However, I don't really know how Vivado manages Tcl packages and how to install new ones.

Comment: In standard Tcl, you need to do `package require json` before you can use `json::json2dict`. For `json::write`, you need to issue `package require json::write`.

Comment: Basically, unless Vivado overrides the package loader itself, all you need to do is put the right directory on the `auto_path` (a global). There is an environment variable to initialize that (whose name escapes me; `TCLLIBPATH`?) and then you should be able to just do a `package require` to load it in.